# AppExchange package or online tool available for tracking user activities in salesforce?

Tags: appexchange

Is there any appexchange tool or package available which can track user's activities such as how many times a user visited a particular vf page, how many times user visited a particular record, how many times user changed a particular field and so on?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Salesforce Shield](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/07/introducing-salesforce-shield.html)? It should do everything you need.

> **Event Monitoring** gives customers unprecedented visibility into their Salesforce apps, letting them easily see what data users are accessing, from what IP address, and what actions are being taken in regards to that data. Customers simply access a standard csv file via API and pull the data into any number of visualization tools. Then, they can track when someone prints a page or list view, edits a record or creates one, changes ownership, refreshes a list, or even when a user exports account data.